# Change tracking behavior changed between EF6 and EF4. How to revert back to Ef4 behavior?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-6

In **EF4** loading an entity from the db and setting its property to the same value as it had previously would still cause an update to be issued to the db.

In **EF6**, the entity seems to be aware that property value has not changed and so does not cause an update to be issued to the DB.

Is it possible to get the EF4 behavior in EF6?

**What I have tried:**

1. Set "context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;". This did not work.
2. Hail Mary: context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false; this also did not work.
3. ((IObjectContextAdapter) context).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.UseLegacyPreserveChangesBehavior = true; Did not work

The reason I need the old EF4 behavior is because the code used to depend on some triggers to update fields (ModifiedDate) and previously EF4 would always cause a save and now EF6 doesnt and this will cause a major regression head-ache!

**Some code that I used to test this:**

```
public void UpdateScenarioWithNoChangesCausesEfToNotPersistChanges()
{
    using (
        TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions()
        {
            IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted
        }))
    {
        using (EnterpriseModel context = new EnterpriseModel())
        {
            //context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false; //did not work
            //context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false; //did not work
            //((IObjectContextAdapter) context).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.UseLegacyPreserveChangesBehavior = true; //did not work

            Guid id = new Guid("3321dbaf-c55e-e411-80cf-00155d0d70c0");
            var efScenario = (from s in context.Scenario
                              where s.ScenarioId == id
                              select s).First();

            DateTime modifiedDateBeforeChanges = efScenario.ModifiedDate;
            //just setting the value back to itself.
            efScenario.ModifiedBy = efScenario.ModifiedBy;

            context.SaveChanges();
            //ef scenario object's ModifiedDate is set as a Computed 
            DateTime modifiedDateAfterChanges = efScenario.ModifiedDate;
            //There is a trigger on Updates that sets the modifiedDate in the database.
            //also ModifiedDate is set as a computed column.

            //the following passes for EF4 and fails for EF6.
            //If in EF6 i do make a change to efScenario.ModifiedBy = efScenario.ModifiedBy; 
            //then EF6 works!
            Assert.AreNotEqual(modifiedDateBeforeChanges, modifiedDateAfterChanges);
        }
    }

}
```

**What has worked:**

1. I can change the ModifiedDate column to some new value and that causes EF to detect a change and causes a save. The trigger updates the modified date and then because the column is marked as computed, EF retrieves the value. (DONT LIKE! as I will have to go through every method that calls SaveChanges and make sure every entity that used to previously get updated, is being updated with a new ModifiedDate value.
2. Calling **context.Entry(efScenario).State = EntityState.Modified;** just before calling SaveChanges. This is no better than (1), in my opinion. And I probably would go with 1 for now.

**My ideal solution:**
A setting that I can toggle in EF that will allow me to get the previous behavior of EF4.

**Bonus Question:**
When did this behavior change in EF? I cant seem to find any document regarding this change!

**Table Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Scenario](
    [ScenarioId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Scenario_ScenarioId]  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()),
    [Name] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Scenario_ModifiedDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Scenario] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ScenarioId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


CREATE TRIGGER  [dbo].[trUpdateModifiedDateScenario]
              ON  [dbo].[Scenario]
              INSTEAD OF UPDATE

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        UPDATE a  SET a.[Name]=b.[Name]
            , a.[ModifiedBy]=b.[ModifiedBy]
            , a.[ModifiedDate]=GETDATE()
        FROM [dbo].[Scenario] a 
        INNER JOIN inserted b 
           ON a.[ScenarioId]=b.[ScenarioId]

    END;
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to tell EF the model changed:

```
var efScenario = (from s in context.Scenario
                  where s.ScenarioId == id
                  select s).First();

context.Entry(efSCenario).State = EntityState.Modified;

context.SaveChanges();  //Should hit the database, it's marked as modified.
```

[MSDN DbContext.Entry()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696578(v=vs.113).aspx)

[MSDN EntityState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.entitystate(v=vs.113).aspx)

> How to revert back to Ef4 behavior?

I don't believe there is some *global* way to revert the behavior, you are going to have to manually do this.

Comment: Do you know when this change occurred (EF5, EF6) and any documentation regarding it?